# Jquery ajax inside function

Tags: jquery, ajax, toggle

```
$(function () {
    $("#rv-title").click(function(event) {
    $("#rv-content").toggle();



  $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=check',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json['output']) {
                $('#cart .content').html(json['output']);
            }
        }
    });  


    event.stopPropagation();
});


$(document).click(function(event) {
    var a = $(event.target).andSelf().parents("#rv-content");
    if (a.length == 0 && $("#rv-content").is(":visible")) {
        $("#rv-content").toggle();
      }
   });
});
```

Where my ajax function is, is that the right place to put it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $("#rv-content").toggle(function(){
    //your ajax call

    });
```

or

```
 $("#rv-content").toggle(function(){

my_ajax();

});

function my_ajax(){

//ajax call

}
```

Comment: In your opinion, which one is more efficient?

Comment: second one, because you can call my_ajax() function multiple time. Because. writing same think again again is waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function as a parameter to your toggle call.
e.g.

```
$("#rv-content").toggle(function(){ /* put your code here... */ });
```

see: 
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/